# Export imported modules using Typescript AMD

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

Assuming I've implemented this two interesting Typescript libraries as AMD modules.

**MathBasics.ts**

```
module MathBasics {
    export function add(a: number, b: number) {
        return a + b;
    }
    export function substract(a: number, b: number) {
        return a - b;
    }
}
export = MathBasics
```

**MathAdvanced.ts**

```
module MathAdvanced {
    export function mult(a: number, b: number) {
        return a * b;
    }
    export function div(a: number, b: number) {
        return a / b;
    }
}
export = MathAdvanced
```

How can I combine them in one MathAll.ts library so client code doesn't have to reference both of it.

**MathAll.ts**

```
import MathBasics = require("MathBasics");
import MathAdvanced = require("MathAdvanced"); 

module MathAll {
    export var MathBasics: MathBasics;  
    export var MathAdvanced : MathAdvanced;
    //Error: Type reference cannot refer to container 

    export module MathBasics;
    export module MathAdvanced;
    //Error: '{' expected

    export MathBasics;
    export MathAdvanced;
    //Error: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.

}

export = MathAll;
```

I don't care right now whether there are 1 or 3 requests being made. My question is more about development convenience than performance.

Comment: What is more convenient about `import MathAll = require('MathAll'); var MathBasics = MathAll.MathBasics;` than `import MathBasics = require('MathBasics');`?

Comment: If instead of two modules the are like 10 clossely related ones, in one case you have auto completion while in the other you need to know the names of each module.

Comment: One of the ideas of modules is to prevent you from doing exactly what you try to do.  Thus, it is not a good idea at all.  A module is supposed to be closed and self-contained, acting as a "unit".  Your MathAll is not a module at all since it can be "added" to.  Mutable modules sort of destroy all the nice things about using modules and you mind as well start writing non-AMD JS code.

Comment: Got further helpful variations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712638/typescript-export-imported-interface/30714301#30714301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the following two lines to your `MathAll.ts` file:

```
export import MathBasics = require("MathBasics");
export import MathAdvanced = require("MathAdvanced");
```

This will allow you to essentially import both using the `MathAll` psudeo-module...

```
import math = require('./MathAll');

math.MathAdvanced....
```

But it can play some havoc with your auto-completion and there were some hints that this may be disallowed in the future, which will then break your program - so beware of using this trick.

So now I have shown how you *could* do it, hopefully you'll accept my suggestion that you don't do it (because you know I'm not saying "don't do it" just because I don't know *how* you could do it).

Organise your modules in a way that makes each one sensible to import in its own right. Is it such a hardship to import `MathBasics` when I need it, and `MathAdvanced` when I need it?

If you are hiding implementation details, that is another matter - but you definitely aren't hiding implementation details when you `export import` - because you are showing off all the details by exporting them straight out.

Comment: Hey, this does work and generates the right MathAll.js, but its true that auto-completion does not work, so I will reconsider my design to be more independent and not so hierarchical. Thanks!

Comment: I think the origin of my confusion is treating modules too much as namespaces, while once you use require.js they should be treated as assemblies.

Comment: Kind of - you can still use a folder structure to organise them, which acts like namespaces, i.e. `./Travel/Railways/Train.ts`